# NPE on createPrimaryKey. How to correctly map these two entities?

Tags: jpa

I have two entities, `Credential` and `Account`. Every `Account` must have a unique `Credential`, and each `Credential` must have a unique e-mail address and a unique username. I intend to add more atributes to `Account` later, so I isolated some atributes to a `Credential` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Credential {

@Id
@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private String email;

@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private String nickname;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String password;
```

And my `Account` atribute:

```
@Entity
public class Account {

@Id
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "email", referencedColumnName = "email")
private Credential credential;

@Column(nullable = false)
private long level;

@Column(nullable = false)
private boolean loggedIn;
```

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5805561/3026886) and decided to use `PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` notation. When I try to instantiate a `EntityManagerFactory`, I get this stack error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.createPrimaryKey(PersistentClass.java:363)
```

There are more lines, but none of them has `Credential` or `Account` on it. On my `persistence.xml` I have these main differences from standard file:

```
 <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>entity.PersistentEntity.Credential</class>
    <class>entity.PersistentEntity.Account</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="tomee.jpa.factory.lazy" value="true"/>
        //unchanged stuff before it stopped working
```

I'm using Intellij with TomEE 8.5.6 with JPA 2.0 and I have to set that property as stated [here](http://tomee-openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/CDI-issues-tomee-7-0-2-td4680584.html). Given this scenario, here are my questions:

1. What is causing NPE?
2. There are obviously good coding pratices I'm missing? If so, which ones are they?
3. What is the best way to map this entities, given my entity logic at question's beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered I was wrongly using `PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3419000/3026886) and this notation was from JPA1.0. Now with JPA2.0 I can use `@Id + @JoinColumn` 
 as stated on previous link and on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4215566/3026886).
 My problem was solved and now both tables use `email` field from `Credential` as PK.